# Plugin Post 2 Posts: How to list most connected posts?

Tags: plugins, plugin-posts-to-posts

I want to list the most connected posts ordered by quantity. ¿Is it possible? ¿Could anyone help me with that? I explain with an example: let's say I have `Movies` custom post type and an `Actors` custom post type, that are connected with `Posts 2 Posts`. In the Actors archive, I want to **order them by the number of Movies that they have worked on**.

I think it is maybe possible with [`each_connected()`](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected), but I don't know how to order the `$wp_query` array by the number of elements in `connected` subarray for every `$post`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this way:

```
// Find connected pages (for all posts)
p2p_type( 'actors_movies' )->each_connected( $wp_query );
```

Now we have a `$connected` property attached to every post on the `$wp_query`, that is an array of posts connected by `actors_movies`.

```
$actors = array();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $movies_acted = count($post->connected);
    if($movies_acted > 0) {
        $actors[$post->ID] = $movies_acted; 
    }
endwhile;
arsort($actors);
foreach ($actors as $id => $quantity) {
    //Show the actor info
}
```

Then, I have made an array with the `ID` of the `$post` as the `key`, and the quantity of `$connected` as the `value`, for each. Then I have ordered it by the `value`, and I have done a `foreach` through the array, to get the post from every `ID`, starting from the most prolific =D